# postgres: left join by unknown table - column value

Tags: postgresql

I know this is a stupid question, but I'm gotta ask away.

I'm in a situation where the db I'm working on doesn't have a "backwards" relation to another table.

Let's say I have three tables - let's call them type tables, `rt`, `wt`, and `ret`.

Each of those tables has a group_id.

Each `group` table has `type` which may contain rt, wt, or ret.

The normal procedure for selection is select from a type table and then left join group on group_id.

I'm in a situation where I need to select in the reverse order, but I don't know which table I'm to be selecting from at run time. All I have is the type.

Is there such a thing as selecting a table by a column value? such as

```
SELECT * FROM group LEFT JOIN `group.type` ON `group.type`.group_id = group.id
```

Comment: I suppose you could do some dynamic SQL inside a function (ick) or LEFT JOIN them all and then COALESCE to collapse the values. What do these three tables look like?

Comment: @muistooshort I reckon that is the correct answer. It seemed a little strange to left join all of them, but it turns out that's how it's been done before on this db.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just did multiple left joins, of course only one of them stuck.